# Filtering dates in R

Tags: r, database, filter, dplyr

I'm having issues with filtering my dataset into a specific date. I'm not sure how to upload the dataset on here but here is the link for it https://sexualitics.github.io . I'm trying to explore porn trends over the years focusing on 2007 first then 2008, 2009 etc. However, nothing has worked from what I have tried.

```
library(dplyr)
install.packages("tibbletime")
library(tibbletime)
as.Date(xhamster$upload_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

filter(xhamster, date >= as.Date("2013-01-01"), date <= as.Date("2013-12-31"))
```

other things I have tried include:

```
xhamster %>%
  select(upload_date) %>%
  filter(xhamster$upload_date >= as.Date("2007-01-01"), as.Date("2007-12-31"))
```

as well as:

```
NewDate <- filter(xhamster$upload_date, date("2007-01-01":"2007-12-31"))
```

and:

```
subset(xhamster$upload_date,date>"2007-01-01" & date < "2007-12-31")
```

There have been getting numerous errors no matter what method I try. These are some examples of the errors I have gotten:

```
Error in "2007-01-01":"2007-12-31" : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In date("2007-01-01":"2007-12-31") : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In date("2007-01-01":"2007-12-31") : NAs introduced by coercion

Error in date > "2007-01-01" : 
  comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types

Error: comparison (5) is possible only for atomic and list types

Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x argument "right" is missing, with no default
ℹ Input `..1` is `between(upload_date >= as.Date("2007-01-01"), as.Date("2007-12-31"))`.
```

Comment: i believe you forgot to overwrite the object in the in `as.Date(xhamster$upload_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")`. try `xhamster$upload_date <- as.Date(xhamster$upload_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")`. if it does not solve, please provide a sample of your data with `dput(head(xhamster, 10))` and include the output in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several places you can find out how to solve this.

One example: https://www.gormanalysis.com/blog/dates-and-times-in-r-without-losing-your-sanity/

But i understand you are new to R, and get stuck at small errors. I think your error is in formating the date. You need to help R to interpret the text.

Try this:

```
xhamster$upload_date <- as.Date(xhamster$upload_date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

##Then you can do the filtering

filtered_data <- xhamster[(xhamster$upload_date>="2013-01-01" & xhamster$upload_date <= "2013-12-01"),]
```